# How to iterate through nested object in Angular 2 using Type Script?

Tags: arrays, json, typescript, foreach

Hi I am developing web application using Angular 2. I am receiving JSON data using API. I am trying to segregate data. Below is my JSON data.

```
[  
   {  
      "userid":"f8b7b393-b36d-412b-82f7-9500e9eb6924",
      "tenantid":"7a4a4ea9-3b39-4ef6-8d00-fcfe7454888c",
      "username":"testuser3",
      "emailaddress":"testuser3@rkdssravioutlook.onmicrosoft.com",
      "isallowed":false,
      "userroles":[  
         {  
            "userroleid":"c4c64675-ffe0-467b-87a4-00b899e0d48e",
            "userid":"f8b7b393-b36d-412b-82f7-9500e9eb6924",
            "roleid":"ada09fb2-fa83-4e46-8878-7e4e48c73111",
            "tenantappid":1,
            "validfrom":"2018-01-24T00:00:00",
            "validto":"2018-01-24T00:00:00",
            "isactive":true,
            "isdeleted":false,
            "role":{  
               "roleid":"ada09fb2-fa83-4e46-8878-7e4e48c73111",
               "rolename":"Installer",
               "tenantid":"99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999",
               "isactive":true,
               "isdeleted":false,
               "actionnames":null,
               "scopeids":null,
               "scopes":null,
               "actionids":null,
               "actions":null
            }
         },
         {  
            "userroleid":"bf632c7b-7540-479e-b8ec-b1471efd7f93",
            "userid":"f8b7b393-b36d-412b-82f7-9500e9eb6924",
            "roleid":"80dc8c6a-a934-4c2e-9d17-7cdd5b774fc6",
            "tenantappid":1,
            "validfrom":"2018-01-24T00:00:00",
            "validto":"2018-01-24T00:00:00",
            "isactive":true,
            "isdeleted":false,
            "role":{  
               "roleid":"80dc8c6a-a934-4c2e-9d17-7cdd5b774fc6",
               "rolename":"Operator",
               "tenantid":"99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999",
               "isactive":true,
               "isdeleted":false,
               "actionnames":null,
               "scopeids":null,
               "scopes":null,
               "actionids":null,
               "actions":null
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "userid":"8363def7-7547-425c-8d55-2116dd703cfc",
      "tenantid":"7a4a4ea9-3b39-4ef6-8d00-fcfe7454888c",
      "username":"testuser1",
      "emailaddress":"testuser1@rkdssravioutlook.onmicrosoft.com",
      "isallowed":false,
      "userroles":[  
         {  
            "userroleid":"fe2b1f9f-4cd8-48dc-9708-2637e9743c1d",
            "userid":"8363def7-7547-425c-8d55-2116dd703cfc",
            "roleid":"ada09fb2-fa83-4e46-8878-7e4e48c73111",
            "tenantappid":1,
            "validfrom":"2018-01-24T00:00:00",
            "validto":"2018-01-24T00:00:00",
            "isactive":true,
            "isdeleted":false,
            "role":{  
               "roleid":"ada09fb2-fa83-4e46-8878-7e4e48c73111",
               "rolename":"Installer",
               "tenantid":"99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999",
               "isactive":true,
               "isdeleted":false,
               "actionnames":null,
               "scopeids":null,
               "scopes":null,
               "actionids":null,
               "actions":null
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "userid":"7f359233-5940-4b93-8ec9-fcf39e2fb58f",
      "tenantid":"7a4a4ea9-3b39-4ef6-8d00-fcfe7454888c",
      "username":"testuser2",
      "emailaddress":"testuser2@rkdssravioutlook.onmicrosoft.com",
      "isallowed":false,
      "userroles":[  
         {  
            "userroleid":"c479b1c0-5275-40b2-893e-fc82dc55f1a5",
            "userid":"7f359233-5940-4b93-8ec9-fcf39e2fb58f",
            "roleid":"4dd2803b-e723-4356-8381-7c514ba13247",
            "tenantappid":1,
            "validfrom":"2018-01-24T00:00:00",
            "validto":"2018-01-24T00:00:00",
            "isactive":true,
            "isdeleted":false,
            "role":{  
               "roleid":"4dd2803b-e723-4356-8381-7c514ba13247",
               "rolename":"Engineer",
               "tenantid":"99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999",
               "isactive":true,
               "isdeleted":false,
               "actionnames":null,
               "scopeids":null,
               "scopes":null,
               "actionids":null,
               "actions":null
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Below are my corresponding models.

```
export class UserModel {
 public userid: string;
    public tenantid: string;
    public isallowed: boolean;
    public emailaddress: string;
    public upn: string;
    public userroles: UserRole[];
    public roleid: string;
    public isactive: boolean;
    public tenantappid: string;
    public username: string;
    public userrolestext: string;
    public validfrom: string;
    public validto: string;
}
```

Below is role model

```
export class UserRole {
 public userid: string;
 public roleid: string;
 public role: Role;
}
```

Below is the sample data i am trying to get

```
[
{
"userid":"f8b7b393-b36d-412b-82f7-9500e9eb6924",
"tenantid":"7a4a4ea9-3b39-4ef6-8d00-fcfe7454888c",
"rolename":"Installer",
"rolename":"Operator",
},
{
//rest of the data
}
]
```

First array of above object contains userid and below it contains again array of userroles. So i am trying to get each rolename associated with userid in a single row.

Below code i tried.

```
 users.forEach(eachObj => {
                eachObj.userroles.forEach(nestedeachObj => {

                });
            });
```

I am not able to go forward in the above foreach loop. Can someone help me to segregate above data? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by not able to go forwards? Whats the error? The code you tried looks correct to me at first glance

Comment: the sample data you're trying to get doesn't make sense: you have several times the same property (rolename) in the same object. What are you actually trying to achieve?What's wrong with the model you have (i.e. UerModel having an array of UserRole)?

Comment: Hi Plog. I stucked at nested for each loop.

Comment: Hi JB Nizet. Lets say i do not have strongly typed object. Then how can i iterate?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Edit your question, and explain what you really want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I really don't know if my code example will achieve what you are looking for but what my example is creating looks like this:

**RESULT:**

```
[
 {
  tenantid: "7a4a4ea9-3b39-4ef6-8d00-fcfe7454888c", 
  userid: "f8b7b393-b36d-412b-82f7-9500e9eb6924", 
  rolename: "Operator"
 },
 {
  tenantid: "7a4a4ea9-3b39-4ef6-8d00-fcfe7454888c", 
  userid: "8363def7-7547-425c-8d55-2116dd703cfc", 
  rolename: "Installer"
 },
 {
  tenantid: "7a4a4ea9-3b39-4ef6-8d00-fcfe7454888c", 
  userid: "7f359233-5940-4b93-8ec9-fcf39e2fb58f", 
  rolename: "Engineer"
 }
]
```

**CODE:**

```
 const getRelevantData = (array) => {

           data.forEach((user) => {        
             const obj = {};

             obj.tenantid = user.tenantid;
             obj.userid = user.userid;

             user.userroles.forEach((userrole) => {
                obj.rolename = userrole.role.rolename;
             });

             array.push(obj);         
          });
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added below code and worked fine.

```
 this.userroleData = [];
            results.forEach(eachObj => {
                eachObj.userroles.forEach(nestedeachObj => {
                    this.userroleData.push({
                        username: eachObj.username,
                        userrolestext: nestedeachObj.role.rolename,
                    });
                });
            });
```